# EXCEL VBA How can i change an IF (loop) for something else?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have this code that works but it takes a lot of time I´m sure there is a way to optimize it I did some research but i couldn't find how. My files are really big **(100mb+)** so anything that makes this code faster its necessary.

```
lastrowLaneTemplate = Sheets("LaneTemplate").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
lastrowCarrier = Sheets("Routed").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
lastrowCarrierd = Sheets("Routed").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row

 j = 2
  For i = 10 To lastrowLanetemplate
    For z = 2 To lastrowCarrier
     If Sheetlanetemplate.Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" Then
     If Sheetlanetemplate.Cells(i, 4) = sheetCarrier.Cells(z, 1) And _
     sheetCarrier.Cells(z, 3) = "1" Then

     sheetcarrierd.Cells(j, 1) = sheetCarrier.Cells(z, 1)
     sheetcarrierd.Cells(j, 2) = sheetCarrier.Cells(z, 2)
     sheetcarrierd.Cells(j, 3) = sheetCarrier.Cells(z, 3)
     sheetcarrierd.Cells(j, 4) = sheetCarrier.Cells(z, 4)
     sheetcarrierd.Cells(j, 5) = sheetCarrier.Cells(z, 5)
     sheetcarrierd.Cells(j, 6) = sheetCarrier.Cells(z, 6)
     sheetcarrierd.Cells(j, 7) = sheetCarrier.Cells(z, 7)
     sheetcarrierd.Cells(j, 8) = sheetCarrier.Cells(z, 8)
     sheetcarrierd.Cells(j, 9) = sheetCarrier.Cells(z, 9)
     sheetcarrierd.Cells(j, 10) = sheetCarrier.Cells(z, 10)
     sheetcarrierd.Cells(j, 11) = sheetCarrier.Cells(z, 11)

     j = j + 1
  End if
 Next z
Next y
```

As you can see that works but it takes some time and I have 10 times that.So if there is a way to do this without IF it would be perfect

Comment: excel is not the right tool for this, if you'd like i can help you with a script in a different language

Comment: Store the area of interest in a variant array. Then, also store the new values you want to keep in another variant array. Finally, paste that other variant array on the area of interest.

Comment: -IF i use arrays it takes much more time. Each loop has its data they re different.

which tool should i use for this? im creating a macro that analyses a lo of data and after that writes on a template.

Comment: Arrays should a whole lot faster, but you need to implement them right. For example this oneliner gets all data in one go very quickly:
vData = sheetCarrier.Range("A1:A10000").Value

Comment: Done but still takes a lot of time in my opinion i think i need to change the loops not use arrays or not.

Answer (score 1):

My quick idea is to change 11 lines inside `if...end if` statement into one line:

```
sheetcarrierd.Range(sheetcarrierd.Cells(j, 1), sheetcarrierd.Cells(j, 11)).Value = _
        sheetCarrier.Range(sheetCarrier.Cells(Z, 1), sheetCarrier.Cells(Z, 11)).Value
```

but I'm not sure if it would improve performance significantly.

Comment: That simplifies code but the If is still there which is my main problem i think.

This excel (100mb+) is looping all the time and that consumes a lot of time.
Thanks!

Comment: both sheets `sheetcarrierd` and `sheetCarrier` are in the same workbook?

Comment: Yes everything is in the same wokbook

Answer (score 1):

Are you already using these?

At start:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

At the end:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Yes, there are tons of code before and after that.

That loop  its my main concern I have like 10 loops like that one  Im sure that can be done differently.